# How to Specify Currency When Retrieving Monthly Revenue per Video using YouTube Reporting API

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the YouTube Reporting API's System-Managed Reports to retrieve the 'Aggregate ad revenue per video' on a monthly basis as detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/system_managed/financial-reports?hl=ja#aggregate-ad-revenue-per-video).

However, the revenue data is returned in USD, and I am looking for a way to specify the currency, ideally to get the revenue data in JPY.

I have not found a parameter or an option in the documentation that allows for specifying the currency.
I was expecting to find a method or a parameter that would allow me to retrieve the revenue data in JPY or another specified currency.
Any insights or examples on how to specify the currency would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs you will see that [Aggregate ad revenue per video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/system_managed/financial-reports#aggregate-ad-revenue-per-video)

returns [partner_revenue](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/system_managed/fields#FIELD-partner_revenue) which is

> Your revenue in USD from advertising after the revenue share split has been applied. This field appears in YouTube ads reports. The youtube_revenue_split field contains the total revenue before the revenue share split was applied.

This report doesnt return in local currency it returns in the default currency.

You need to find a report that will return partner_revenue_local